# Modify arraylist through textfields

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I currently have a class `Room` and a class `Hostel` which holds `rooms = new ArrayList < Room >();`. I then have a `BookRoomGUI` class.

When a room is added to the arraylist it uses the following constructor:

```
public Room(int newRoomNo, boolean newRoomEnSuite)
{
    roomNo = newRoomNo;
    roomEnSuite = newRoomEnSuite;
    roomBooking = "Free";
    roomNights = 0;
    roomBooker = "No Booker";
}
```

In the `BookRoomGUI` class i have the following JTextFields:

```
    fields.add(roomnumberJTextField);
    fields.add(bookerJtextField);
    fields.add(nightsJTextField);
    fields.add(peoplenoJTextField);
```

I am trying to make a method within `Hostel` which will take the values of these text fields and alter the corresponding variables in the original constructor if the room number matches:

```
public int makeBooking(int number)
{
  for (Room room : rooms)
  {
     if (number == room.getRoomNo())
     {
         room.setRoomBooker(bookRoom.booker);
     }
  }
}
```

My question is what should go in the if statement? currently i use `booker = bookerJtextField.getText();` to take the text from the text field in `BookRoomGUI` and setRoomBooker in `Room` but this does not work and i am presented with

> setRoomBooker() in Room cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)

Comment: It would be better to store the rooms in a `number -> Room` map instead of list. Make sure you have `setRoomBooker(String)` method in `Room` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the following method in `Room`:

```
public void setRoomBooker(String roomBooker) {
    this.roomBooker = roomBooker;
}
```

Right now, if you look at the error messege:

> setRoomBooker() in Room cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)

You can see that your `setRoomBooker()` method currently is not defined to take a parameter of type `java.lang.String` (or any parameter at all).

So, you need to change the definition of that method, for you to be able to do the following:

```
room.setRoomBooker(bookRoom.booker); //<-- You are passing it an argument of type String
```

Comment: Would this mean i need to alter the getRoomNumber method also?

Comment: No. It has nothing  do with getRoomNumber method. Are you sure that your `Room` class has the above method?

Comment: taken a step back and just attempted to modify the arraylist without the GUI to start, your fix worked though, thanks.